# What's wrong with my code to get last insert id?

Tags: php, php-mysqlidb

This is my code to insert date to database. Everything is fine except I cannot get insert_id.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $data_to_store = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    $db = getDbInstance();
    $Stats = $db->insert ('images', $data_to_store);
    $last_id = $db->insert_id();

    if($Stats)
    {
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Record added successfully!";
        header('location: index.php');
        exit();
    }  
}
```

It shows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MysqliDb::insert_id() in
```

My db:

```
 function getDbInstance() { 
    return new MysqliDb(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME); 
 }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should provide more info, about `getDbInstance()` and `insert_id()`

Comment: function getDbInstance()
{
 return new MysqliDb(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME); 
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I know `MysqliDb` does not have a last insert id function like you've tried : `insert_id`.

There are two ways to go about it.

1. Change the library to avail something like this [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) or
2. You can simply run a select query and fetch the last id in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP's class for `mysqli` is called `mysqli`, I'm guessing you're using [`PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class`](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class), whose class name is `MysqliDb`. This information is important and missing in your post, superb!

If you take a look at the class, you'll see that there is no function called `insert_id` with 0 parameters. The function you're looking for is called `getInsertId`. As found in the [source](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L1404).

Answer (score -1):

`insert_id` is a property not a method so it should not have the parenthesis. so it should be

```
$last_id = $db->insert_id;
```

not

```
$last_id = $db->insert_id();
```

Comment: His $db isn't of the mysqli class.